# Users on the favorites tab are incorrect

Tags: bug, users

On the favorite tab, the users displayed are completely incorrect. The users have no affiliation to the question displayed, and this can be verified when visiting one of the questions.

[image: Incorrect peoplez]

Comment: Seems to be okay when I look at my favourites...

Comment: Oooh, no. There we go. So it breaks when I switch to the 'Votes' sort.

Comment: It's quite possible those users were the last to interact with those questions, but they had their comment/answer removed or hidden via moderation. That could explain the 3 rep 'Pi' user, but not so much the other two.

Answer (score 1):

## [Why does Windows think that my wireless keyboard is a toaster?](https://superuser.com/questions/792607/why-does-windows-think-that-my-wireless-keyboard-is-a-toaster)

That user had a bounty on the question on that date.

## [What are the Windows A: and B: drives used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for)

[Last edit to the question](https://superuser.com/posts/231273/revisions)

## [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

[Last edit to an answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1124054/revisions)

---

Whether that's sensible to show, I don't know. But at least there's nothing obviously broken.

Comment: Ah I see. Thats really confusing though.

Comment: The fact that "community wiki" posts don't display the name of the last editor adds to the fog.  (You have to *click on* the date/time of last edit to get the revision history, where you can see the names of all the editors.)